# Limited space average computation

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

Let's say I have N integers, where N can get huge, but each int is guaranteed to be between 0 and some cap M, where M fits easily in a signed 32-bit field.

If I want to compute the average of these N integers, I can't always just sum and divide them all in the same signed 32-bit space - the numerator carries a risk of overflow if N is too large.  One solution to this problem is to just use 64-bit fields for the computation, to hold for larger N, but this solution doesn't scale - If M were a large 64-bit integer instead, the same problem would arise.

Does anyone know of an algorithm (preferably O(N)) that can compute the average of a list of positive integers in the same bit-space?  Without doing something cheap like using two integers to simulate a larger one.

Comment: Can you clarify your restriction of "without doing something cheap?"  Are you specifically restricting the memory usage to just a single integer?  Also, what's wrong with just using the next-largest integer type?

Comment: I suppose it really is a trivial problem the more I think about it - By "doing something cheap", I mean doing anything that effectively simulates an Arbitrary Precision Integer, like java.math.BigInteger - I'm wondering if there's a solution that bypasses the need for such a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing you know `M` initially, you can keep two variables, one is the answer so far divided by M, and the other is the remainder.

For example, in C++:

```
int ans = 0, remainder = 0;
for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
  remainder += input[i]; // update remainder so far
  ans += remainder/N; // move what we can from remainder into ans
  remainder%=N; // calculate what's left of remainder
}
```

At the end of the loop, the answer is found in `ans`, with a remainder in `remainder` (if you need a rounding method other than truncation).

This example works where the maximum input number M+N fits in a 32-bit int.

Note that this should work for positive and negative integers, because in C++, the `/` operator is the division operator, and `%` is actually a remainder operator (not really a modulo operator).

Comment: Where is N in all of this?  M isn't the number of inputs, just an upper bound on the value of each one

Comment: sorry, I mixed up M and N, changed variable name `M` to `N`.

Comment: Doesn't this force `ans` to be a floating point, though?  Which is no different than using a larger integer type, really - consider, for example, the list with N = 1000, and every element = 999

Comment: No, it is an integer, and I am using integer division. `ans` gives the integer closest to the real answer, which is truncated towards zero (rounded down for +ve values). If you want the true floating point answer, you can get this at the end by using: `ans+((double)remainder)/N`.

Comment: Technically, this is "using two integers to simulate a larger one", no? But it's clearly the right answer, so +1.

Comment: Yes, it is kind of using two integers to simulate a larger one. Unfortunately, compilers do not natively allow us to declare integers with an arbitrarily large number of bits (currently only up to 128-bit), so there are times when this sort of thing is required. It has similarities to [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), which "uses two floating point numbers to simulate a floating point number of greater precision"

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate a running average. If you have the average `A` of `N` elements, and you add another element `E`, the new average is `(A*N+E)/(N+1)`. By the distributive property of division over addition, this is equivalent to `(A*N)/(N+1) + E/(N+1)`. But if `A*N` overflows, you can use the associative property of multiplication and division, you can convert the first term to `A*(N/N+1)`.

So the algorithm is:

```
n = 0
avg = 0
for each i in list
  avg = avg*(n/(n+1)) + i/(n+1)
  n = n+1
```